# Matlab and Mathematica : Finding the density function

Tags: matlab, statistics, wolfram-mathematica

The pdf of a standard Gamma distribution is  `$f(x) = \frac{x^{\gamma-1} \exp(-x)}{\Gamma(\gamma)}$`. How do I find the pdf of of the random variable `Z = X + Y` where `Y` is the Normal distribution? There is no closed form analytical solution, and it is very difficult to start analytically. SO, was wondering if there is a way to use software tools that will compute the pdf using convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I find the pdf of of the random variable Z = X + Y where Y is
>   the Normal distribution?

So you must mean X is the Gamma distribution. In Mathematica:

```
d = TransformedDistribution[x + y, 
   {Distributed[x, GammaDistribution[alpha, beta]], 
   Distributed[y, NormalDistribution[mu, std]]}];
PDF[d, x] // Simplify
```

gives

```
 (1/(Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[alpha]))*((2^(-2 + alpha/2)*beta^(-1 - alpha)*
 std^(-2 + alpha)*             
  (Sqrt[2]*beta*std*Gamma[alpha/2]*Hypergeometric1F1[alpha/2, 1/2, 
  (std^2 + beta*(mu - x))^2/(2*beta^2*std^2)] - 
            2*(std^2 + beta*(mu - x))*Gamma[(1 + alpha)/2]*
        Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + alpha)/2, 3/2, (std^2 + beta
    *(mu - x))^2/(2*beta^2*std^2)]))/
      E^((mu - x)^2/(2*std^2)))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Mean[d]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Variance[d]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot for some parameters

```
 Plot[pdf /. {mu -> 0, std -> 1, alpha -> 1, beta -> 2}, {x, -3, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[pdf /. {mu -> .5, std -> 2, alpha -> 1, beta -> 5}, {x, -6, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great!! Thank you. Can this be done in Matlab as well since I don't have access to Mathematica from my University. One last Question, if the pdf generalized gamma, then I need to specify the functional form. I cannot use the command (is it in built ?) GammaDistribution. In that case, how do I use it? I have posted a question here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140164/what-is-the-pdf-of-a-sum-of-generalized-gamma-and-normal-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment269455_140164 mentioning the problem. Can you please have a look at this? Thank you

Comment: mathematica supports a generalized gamma distribution (four arguments to the `GammaDistribution` function) and has a function `ProbabilityDistribution` to construct a distribution if you know the PDF.